# How to send image data to Swift with sharedGroupPreferences in React Native?

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

I have a React Native app, and I am trying to create a widget that displays on the home screen on iOS using images from the app. How do I get the Swift code to receive image data and display it?

I am currently passing a text string to the Swift component:

```js
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents

struct WidgetData: Decodable {
  var text: String
}

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
  func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
    SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), text: "Placeholder")
  }
  
  func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, text: "Data goes here")
    completion(entry)
  }
  
  func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> Void) {
    let entryDate = Date()
    
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.noisolation.ev1-debug.HomePhotos")
    if userDefaults != nil {
      if let savedData = userDefaults!.value(forKey: "savedData") as? String {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let data = savedData.data(using: .utf8)
        
        if let parsedData = try? decoder.decode(WidgetData.self, from: data!) {
          let nextRefresh = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: entryDate)!
          let entry = SimpleEntry(date: nextRefresh, configuration: configuration, text: parsedData.text)
          let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
          
          completion(timeline)
        } else {
          print("Could not parse data")
        }
        
      } else {
        let nextRefresh = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: entryDate)!
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: nextRefresh, configuration: configuration, text: "No data set")
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .atEnd)
        
        completion(timeline)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
  let date: Date
  let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
  let text: String
}

struct HomePhotosEntryView : View {
  var entry: Provider.Entry
  
  var body: some View {
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
      .overlay(
        VStack {
          Text(entry.text)
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }.padding(20)
      )
  }
}

@main
struct HomePhotos: Widget {
  let kind: String = "HomePhotos"
  
  var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
      HomePhotosEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    .description("This is an example widget.")
  }
}

struct HomePhotos_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    HomePhotosEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), text: "Widget preview"))
      .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
  }
}
```

The react native component passing the string:

```js
import SharedGroupPreferences from 'react-native-shared-group-preferences';

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    await SharedGroupPreferences.setItem(
      'savedData', // this is a key to pull from later in Swift
      {displayText: 'Hello'},
      appGroupIdentifier,
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({error});
  }
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I am also trying to find a solution for this.
Did you find anything about this?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should read https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios for your app, because image from react native is id of map, not image in native. You can use image same below.
example:

`--React Native--

```
const myImage = require('assets/images/yasuo.png');
 const resolveAssetSource = require('react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource');
await BeautyWidgetModule.doSomething(resolveAssetSource(myImage));`

--Native--

`RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(doSomething:(id) imagePath) {
  NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", bundlePath, imagePath];
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
}`
```